# Returning unions in TypeGraphQL

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

So i have this code:

```
const getAllUsers = ({
  Model, options,
}) => Model.find(options).catch((e) => {
  throw e;
});

@ObjectType({ description: "User model" })
@Entity()
export class UserModel extends BaseEntity {
    ...
}

@ObjectType()
class Error {
  constructor(data: {message: string, code: number}) {
    this.message = data.message;
    this.code = data.code;
  }
  @Field(() => Int)
  code: number;
  @Field(() => String)
  message: string;
}

@ObjectType()
class Success {
  @Field(() => [ UserModel ])
  users: [UserModel];
}

const UserResponseType = createUnionType({
  name: "UserResponseType",
  types: () => [
    Success,
    Error,
  ] as const,
});

@Query(() => [ UserResponseType ])
async getAllUsers(): Promise<typeof UserResponseType> {
  const errors = await Promise.resolve([
    new Error({
      code: 501,
      message: "test",
    }),
  ]);
  const users = await getAllUsers({
    Model: UserModel,
    options: {
      ...
    },
  }).catch((e) => e);
  return {
    errors,
    success: users,
  };
}
```

All i want to do is return Errors or success so I can do this in a query:

```
query getAllUsers {
  getAllUsers {
    ... on Success {
      user {
        id
        email
      }
    }
    ... on Error {
      code
      message
    }
  }
}
```

But right now I'm getting:

```
TS2322: Type '{ errors: Error[]; success: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Error | Success'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'errors' does not exist in type 'Error | Success'.
```

I was trying to kind of copy (https://typegraphql.com/docs/unions.html#docsNav)[this example)
So how can achieve the mentioned above ability to query?

Comment: why non standard error handling? errors shouldn't be returned as data

Comment: That's a part of a big learning curve now. How should I return errors? In REST I would just return them as `res.json({error:{code:5xx, message: "..."})`. How else do I handle it in GraphQL? Also that's wjat I found online

Comment: Here https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-graphql-errors-like-a-champ-with-unions-and-interfaces/?fbclid=IwAR01vZ8IFH02cyzL1f1_9edKmbpPpD_z853k87kLIq8jLeAfINdf5nA9pWs

Comment: pros/cons ... not compatible with middleware/logging/hiding details on production/etc ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/ ... just throw some error type with message

Comment: @xadm Exceptions like unable to connect to db? Yes, just throw an error. Domain "errors" like `UserAlreadyExists`? Use dedicated object type and union return type, so you have a type-safe swich-case for the response in the client.

Comment: @MichałLytek switch-case everywhere at every error handling level? any error handling levels considered at all? ... covering only user viewable (for highly specific components) errors only? ... not graphql general specs compatible, no granularity, no retry, re-authentication ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/ https://www.apollographql.com/blog/full-stack-error-handling-with-graphql-apollo-5c12da407210/

Comment: @xadm operation-specific switch-case only in the place you get the data from query or send a mutation. So if the user fill the form and hit a send button, your switch-case can narrow the `UserAlreadyExists` response to react and e.g. highlight the email text input in the form.
https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-graphql-errors-like-a-champ-with-unions-and-interfaces/

Comment: suuuure, one of maybe two use cases where it can be used 'productive way' ... input can be highlighted on validation level ('preflight query' for already existing user login/mail can be done at this level, too) ... 'operation-specific' is sending entire form and doesn't require separate types for very specific error messages ... show an example of larger public API with this typed (nice looking at the first sight) errors solution

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `async getAllUsers()` does not match with the declared return value `Promise<typeof UserResponseType>`, which causes the `TS2322` error.

The function returns an object with `errors` and `success` properties, but it should return either an `Error` or a `Success` instance. Something like this should work:

```js
import {
  createUnionType,  
  Field,
  Int,
  ObjectType,
  Query,
  Resolver,
} from "type-graphql";

@ObjectType({ description: "User model" })
export class UserModel {
  @Field()
  id: string;
}

@ObjectType()
class Error {
  @Field(() => Int)
  code: number;
  @Field(() => String)
  message: string;
}

@ObjectType()
class Success {
  @Field(() => [UserModel])
  users: UserModel[];
}

const UserResponseType = createUnionType({
  name: "UserResponseType",
  types: () => [Success, Error] as const,
  resolveType: (value) => {
    if ("code" in value) {
      return Error;
    }
    if ("users" in value) {
      return Success;
    }
    return undefined;
  },
});

@Resolver()
export class UserResolver {
  @Query(() => UserResponseType)
  async getAllUsers(): Promise<typeof UserResponseType> {
    const error: Error = {
      code: 501,
      message: "test",
    };
    const success: Success = { users: [{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }] };
    return success;
  }
}
```

Running the following query would now return the ids of the users. If you change `return success;` to `return error;`, the query would return the error details.

```
query getAllUsers {
  getAllUsers {
    ... on Success {
      users {
        id
      }
    }
    ... on Error {
      code
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly provide Apollo (the most popular graphql client)+typescript example of this kind error handling ... to be complete (not BE only).

Comment: Is there anything in particular you're interested in? I could try to create a runnable backend and frontend, but it would require a bit more effort. The topic seems to be covered in more detail at https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-graphql-errors-like-a-champ-with-unions-and-interfaces/ , which was discussed in the question comments.

Not advocating or critiquing this error handling approach (Error and Success could be Orange and Apple for the purpose of this answer), just wanted to help out with the TS2322 error in the question.